# How to change @INC in Strawberry Perl?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

How can I change `@INC` permanently, without changing my scripts, in Strawberry Perl?

I'm aware of `-I`, but don't want to invoke that switch every time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To prepend paths, set environment variable PERL5LIB to those paths.

Note: This will affect all installations of Perl you run when this is effect.

Howto: Right-click (My) Computer, Properties, Advanced, Environment Variables, (the top) New.  You will probably have to restart already running consoles to get the change.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use :

```
use lib /my/other/direcotry
```

or

```
push (@INC , /my/other/direcotry)
```

to change the value of `@INC`.

Comment: That would require me to edit my scripts or their invocations, though.