# Unable to install a CPAN module

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I am trying to install a CPAN module Statistics::ChiSquare. I am running Strawbwerry perl and Padre on my Windows 7 machine. First I installed cpan.pm. An then tried to install the module, but got the following error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>cpan App::cpanminus

C:\Windows\System32>perl -MCPAN -e 'install Statistics::ChiSquare'
Set up gcc environment - 4.4.3
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows, you have to use double quotes on the command line:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Statistics::ChiSquare"
```

or simply

```
cpan Statistics::ChiSquare
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked! However I have another issue. Padre couldn't find this module. When I searched it was not part of @INC. Instead it was still under C:\.cpanm. Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806126/how-to-change-inc-in-strawberry-perl